# Openlayers geometry shapes looks distorted on zoom out

Tags: javascript, geometry, zooming, openlayers

[The right image is full zoom in circle whose outline seems distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2SLe.png)I have drawn a circle geometry with Openlayers and the circle is displayed in map . The circle is zoomed when i zoom in/out but on zoom out the circle looks distorted and not perfectly circle after two zoom outs.

I have drawn the circle geometry as per below and update its coordinates dynamic values

```
var circleFeature = new ol.Feature
    ({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([0, 0], 0.4)
    });

circleStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#FFCC00',
                    width: 2,
                    lineDash: [0, 0]
                }),         
                zIndex: 3,
              });

circleFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Circle([100, 110], 0.4));
```

As in below image u can see the circle (or any geometry) to be distored or pixelated on zoom out. On full zoom in the stroke outline seems to have some gaps in stroke color fill. I expect my geometries as in eg: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html. But in my case it not working so

[image: Distorted circle geometry on zoom out]

Comment: Can you post a clearer picture? I can't make anything from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using linedash [0, 0] - if you don't want dashes leave it undefined.  If a feature is going to appear very small when displayed (as when zoomed out) using linedash will produce a poor result.  Perhaps you should replace the circleStyle with a style function which calculates the displayed size and only dashes the result when it is going to be big enough to be seen clearly

```
circleStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    width: 2
                }),         
                zIndex: 3,
              });


circleStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
  var displayRadius;
  if (geometry.getType() = 'Circle') {
    displayRadius = feature.getGeometry().getRadius() / resolution;
  } 
  circleStyle.getStroke().setLineDash( displayRadius >= 10 ? [5, 5] : undefined );
  return circleStyle;
}
```

Comment: Line dash style is not the problem here. Even without that style my circle shape appears collapsed on zoom out as in image. On zoom in image you can notice the circle stroke yellow color is not even its some pixelated

Comment: What is setting it yellow? Your style is red.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake.I have updated the color in above code as per the style i used for drawing that circle